# extracting column data in multiple rows

Tags: python

I have a file that is set up like this:

```
; start item 1
; item 1 line ; start item 2; start item 3
; item 1 line ; item 2 line ; item 3 line ; start item 4
; item 1 line ; item 2 line ; item 3 line ; item 4 line ; start item 5
; item 1 line ; item 2 line
; item 1 line 
; item 1 line

; item 6 start
; item 6 line ; item 7 start
; item 6 line ; item 7 line ; item 8 start
; item 6 line ;; item 8 line
; item 6 line
; item 6 line ; item 9 start
; item 6 line ; item 9 line
; item 6 line
; item 6 line ; item 0 start
; item 6 line ; item 0 line
;; item 0 line
;; item 0 line
```

(imagine the columns are different people and the rows are what they're saying - a row with several columns are several people talking at once.)

I'm trying to parse this so I can get each item separately but I've only been partially successful in doing so. This is my method:

```
def unpacker(File):

    Values = {}
    main_key = 0
    sep = ';'
    with open(File)as fn:
        for line in fn:
            if line.count(sep):
                for i, sub_line in enumerate(line.split(sep)):

                    sub_key=str(main_key)+'_'+str(i)
                    sub_line=sub_line.replace('\n','')

                    if Values.get(sub_key):
                        Values[sub_key]+=('|'+sub_line)
                    else:
                        Values[sub_key]=sub_line

            else:main_key+=1

    for k in Values.keys():
        print k, '---------'
        print Values[k]
```

And its output with the example data:

```
1_3 ---------
 item 8 start| item 8 line
1_2 ---------
 item 7 start| item 7 line || item 9 start| item 9 line| item 0 start| item 0 line| item 0 line| item 0 line
1_1 ---------
 item 6 start| item 6 line | item 6 line | item 6 line | item 6 line| item 6 line | item 6 line | item 6 line| item 6 line | item 6 line ||
1_0 ---------

0_4 ---------
 start item 4| item 4 line 
0_5 ---------
 start item 5
0_2 ---------
 start item 2| item 2 line | item 2 line | item 2 line
0_3 ---------
 start item 3| item 3 line | item 3 line 
0_0 ---------

0_1 ---------
 start item 1| item 1 line | item 1 line | item 1 line | item 1 line | item 1 line | item 1 line
```

Each item is assigned its own key in a dictionary if it wasn't already in it. The lines within each row may differ in length but the semicolon will always be in that pattern.

This method works for the first part of the example above(items 1 to 5), but fails to separate items 7, 9 and 0 apart in the second half (items 6 onwards). The method would work if 7, 9 and 0 were related, but they're not. I've gotten stuck at this point how to differentiate between those items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a code that do the work on your example. You may have do adapt it to real use case :

```
class Speaker(list):
    def __init__(self):
        list.__init__(self)
        self.activated = True

    def talk(self, string):
        if self.activated :
            talk = string.replace("\n", "")
            if talk :
                self.append(talk)
            else:
                self.activated = False

        return self.activated


class SpeakerIndex(dict):
    def __init__(self, filepath, separator):
        """ Creation of index """
        dict.__init__(self)
        self.separator = separator

        self.talk = 0

        self.toSpeak = []
        self.hadSpeak = []
        with open(filepath, 'r') as data:
            for line in data:
                ##print("line: ",line)
                ##print("toSpeak: ",self.toSpeak)
                self.speakersFeed(line)
                #save and remove person tha should have speak
                for speaker in self.toSpeak:
                    self.save_speaker(speaker)
                self.toSpeak = self.hadSpeak
                self.hadSpeak = []

    def speakersFeed(self, line):
        """ parse a line """
        if self.separator in line:
            for speaker_action in line.split(self.separator)[1:]:
                ##print("action :",speaker_action)
                speaker = None
                #Take the good speaker
                if self.toSpeak:
                    speaker = self.toSpeak.pop(0)
                else:
                    speaker = Speaker()
                #process the content
                result = speaker.talk(speaker_action)
                ##print("speaker : ",speaker)
                #put the speaker where is needed depending of its state
                if result :
                    self.hadSpeak.append(speaker)
                else:
                    self.save_speaker(speaker)
        else:
            #save speaker that may be not ended at this point
            for speaker in self.toSpeak:
                self.save_speaker(speaker)
            self.talk +=1

    def speaker_id(self, speaker):
        """ Return an unique Id for speakers """
        number = int(speaker[0].split(" ")[2])
        return "talk{0}-speaker{1}".format(self.talk, number)

    def save_speaker(self, speaker):
        self[self.speaker_id(speaker)]=speaker
        ##print("saved :",speaker)

    def __str__(self):
        """ override the str() comportment """
        keylist = list(self.keys())
        keylist.sort()
        result = "{\n"
        for key in keylist:
            result += "\t" + str(key) + " : " + str(self[key]) + "\n"
        result += "}"
        return result           


if __name__ == "__main__":
    index = SpeakerIndex("foo.txt", ";")
    print(str(index))
```

You may uncomment print line to get execution trace. The idea behind these classes is to maintain a stack of speaker at any moment.

Execution give me this :

```
python3 ./sof.py 
{
    talk0-speaker1 : [' item 1 start', ' item 1 line ', ' item 1 line ', ' item 1 line ', ' item 1 line ', ' item 1 line ', ' item 1 line']
    talk0-speaker2 : [' item 2 start ', ' item 2 line ', ' item 2 line ', ' item 2 line']
    talk0-speaker3 : [' item 3 start', ' item 3 line ', ' item 3 line ']
    talk0-speaker4 : [' item 4 start', ' item 4 line ']
    talk0-speaker5 : [' item 5 start']
    talk1-speaker0 : [' item 0 start', ' item 0 line', ' item 0 line']
    talk1-speaker1 : [' item 1 start', ' item 1 line ', ' item 1 line ', ' item 1 line ', ' item 1 line ', ' item 1 line ', ' item 1 line']
    talk1-speaker6 : [' item 6 start', ' item 6 line ', ' item 6 line ', ' item 6 line ', ' item 6 line', ' item 6 line ', ' item 6 line ', ' item 6 line', ' item 6 line ', ' item 6 line ']
    talk1-speaker7 : [' item 7 start', ' item 7 line ']
    talk1-speaker8 : [' item 8 start', ' item 8 line']
    talk1-speaker9 : [' item 9 start', ' item 9 line']
}
```